# Ruby Byte XOR strange result - help please

Tags: ruby, byte, xor

I was doing some XOR of data and things were going well with my hex based XOR. It was recommend that I use a byte XOR (^) and only work with bytes. I thought that will take no time to change that but I have the some strange behaviour that I had not expected.

---

Could some add a little light as to why I'm getting a different result if I'm processing the string as bytes. I was expecting it to be the same.

```
 m_hex_string ="124f33e6a118566377f237075354541f0a5a1b"
 m_XOR_string ="662756c6c27732065796586974207468652870"
 m_expected ="the code don't work"
 m_expected_hex ="74686520636f646520646f6e277420776f726b"

def XOR_hex_strings(a,b)
  (a.hex ^ b.hex).to_s(16)
end

def XOR_byte_strings(s1,s2) 
   xored = s1.bytes.zip(s2.bytes).map { |(a,b)| a ^ b }.pack('c*')
end

def hex_digest(hexdigest)
   [hexdigest].pack("H*")
end

   puts "My strings for stack overflow"
   puts "'"+hex_digest(XOR_hex_strings(m_hex_string,m_XOR_string))+"'"
   puts "'"+hex_digest(XOR_byte_strings(m_hex_string,m_XOR_string))+"'"
```

---

Results:

```
 My strings for stack overflow
 'the code don't work'
 'tje`#ode ?on't ~mrk'
```

The text should be the same 'the code don't work' for both methods. I'd really like to know why rather than just a correct code fragment. thanks.

Comment: Let me guess: whoever suggested `.bytes` didn't know your strings were hex-strings

Comment: true, and now you've said it. its pretty obvious my mistake as the bytes only works on a strings not hex strings.

Comment: XOR_byte_strings([m_hex_string].pack('H*'),[m_XOR_string].pack('H*'))

Comment: Is this an answer, or a clarification to the question? If it's an answer, you should post it as such (with explanations and the like, if possible)

Comment: I could not post an answer to my own question within 6 hours. This was the conversion for the hex string to a string using pack. The answer below more clearly answers it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments, `bytes` doesn't take the hex format into account, it just returns the integer values for `"1"`, `"2"`, `"4"`, `"f"` etc. You can convert the hex string with [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack):

```
[m_hex_string].pack("H*")
# => "\x12O3\xE6\xA1\x18Vcw\xF27\aSTT\x1F\nZ\e"
```

[`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack) converts this into a byte array, just like [`bytes`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-bytes) but more explicit and faster (IIRC):

```
[m_hex_string].pack("H*").unpack("C*")
# => [18, 79, 51, 230, 161, 24, 86, 99, 119, 242, 55, 7, 83, 84, 84, 31, 10, 90, 27]
```

The final method would look like:

```
def XOR_pack_unpack_strings(s1, s2)
  s1_bytes = [s1].pack("H*").unpack("C*")
  s2_bytes = [s2].pack("H*").unpack("C*")
  s1_bytes.zip(s2_bytes).map { |a, b| a ^ b }.pack('C*')
end
```

If speed is an issue, take a look at the [fast_xor](https://github.com/CodeMonkeySteve/fast_xor) gem:

```
require 'xor'

def XOR_fast_xor_strings(s1_hex, s2_hex)
  s1 = [s1_hex].pack("H*")
  s2 = [s2_hex].pack("H*")
  s1.xor!(s2)
end
```